# How to properly assign new properties to objects in PHP

Tags: php, object

Ok every once in a while I run into this issue.  Say I have a method like the following

```
10 public function myMethod($someVar){
11    $myObject = new stdClass();
12    $myObject->myProperty = $this->some_model->get_some_data_as_object();
13    $myObject->myProperty->subProperty = $someVar;
14 }
```

So then it the above function "works" and the sub-property gets assigned but sometimes php throws a warning like below, and other times there is no warning when assigning properties this way to an object.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Attempt to assign property of non-object
Filename: controllers/MyClass.php
Line Number: 13;
```

So why does the warning only sometimes occur, and how can this be avoided?

Edit: Please note that I am saying that it **"works"**!  The properties get assigned and a dump shows all the values even the one for `subProperty`.  So the warning is saying it does not like assigning the property but it does it anyway.

Edit:  I need to make clarify that `subProperty` does not exist. i.e. it is not part of the data assigned on line 12.  I am both creating the propery and assigning the value on line 13.

Comment: Are you certain that `->get_some_data_as_object()` always returns an object?

Comment: Yes 100% certain.

Comment: Then your problem should be solved! That error occurs when you try to treat scalars or nulls as objects.  I'd recommend doing a `if(!is_object($this->some_model->get_some_data_as_object())){
            echo 'Not an object';
        }` at the start of that function to be sure.

Comment: Also I have noticed that it never happens on my local dev server, just sometimes on a live server.

Comment: `Message: Attempt to assign property of non-object` means that you're **NOT** dealing with an object. Also, "just sometimes on a live server" also means you are not taking care of error checks properly. Therefore, you are 100% certain that you get an object but PHP says you don't?

Answer (score 1):

That might be problem with this

```
$this->some_model->get_some_data_as_object() // It's was giving non-object
```

Added check that if it's a object or not. We can't assign property to non objects

```
if (is_object($myObject->myProperty->subProperty))
{
    $myObject->myProperty->subProperty = $someVar;
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit to my question above. The if statement would fail because I am assigning the property and its value at the same time.  That is where the problem arises I believe.

Answer (score 0):

$myObject->myProperty is null

You have to check:

```
if (isset($myObject->myProperty)) {
    $myObject->myProperty->subProperty = $someVar;
}
```

EDIT: If you want to check that the object is of a certain class you can do:

```
if (is_a($myObject->myProperty, 'MyPropertyClass')) {
    $myObject->myProperty->subProperty = $someVar;
}
```

Comment: Ok that would obviously cause the issue, but it I believe happens at times when `myProperty` is not null

Comment: it can also happen if its value is false or a non-object.

Comment: Note that I said it "works". That is the properties get assigned and the script carrys on like nothing happened.  Just the warning is show.  So it is like PHP is saying you should not do it this way, but it lets you do it anyhow.

Comment: `$a = 4 ;
$a->member = 10;` will trigger the warning